# Catching HTML errors in HTMLLoader / mx:HTML

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm building an application to convert old HTML code to modern, responsive HTML. The app has one text area where the user can enter HTML code which is then displayed in an `mx:HTML` component (using the `htmlText` property). Unfortunately the code to convert has a bunch of errors, such as missing/not closed tags. During debugging I see console messages warning about it, e.g. `about:blank:29 HTML ERROR: <p> is not allowed inside <tr>. Inserting <p> before the <table> instead.` I would like to show these messages in my application but I can't figure out where the traces are created... can anyone help?